# Macports: differences between Python3.2, Python3.3, and Python3.4

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.4, python-3.3, macports

At the moment, I am trying to use Python3.4. However, I am having difficulty installing py34 dependencies using Macports.

Should I use Python3.3? Should I be setting up different PYTHONPATHs? What is the problem here?

What really is the difference between the multiple versions of Python3.x regarding these ports?

Comment: See the [*What's new* documenation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/) for each Python version. The ports just install those different versions.

Comment: Maybe the question you ought to ask is "How can I install py34 with Macports?"  since you are having difficulties. Also any specific errors you are getting when you try to install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What really is the difference between the multiple version of Python3.x

Here is the Python changelog: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/